# Cloud application, database design

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In a cloud application, you would have multiple customers using your service.

Is it possible to keep all customers data in 1 table rather than having to create multiple tables per customer?

Well it is possible but it would slow down the application right? if the customer stops using your service you would want to delete their records aswell. Is there a way to just keep everything in one table and not cause any issues with performance, storage/backup?

EDIT: by separate customer table I mean, tables such as PRODUCT, INVOICE, etc these tables are specific to a customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need some more details of your requirements, but my guess is that no the table will be sufficiently sized so long there are appropriate indexes on the table and updated statistics.

Keep all customer data in a single table, that is the best design. It is a simple DML batch to delete all customer data from a table if necessary.

Comment: If you were to design "freshbooks" each customer will have their own tables or the same tables for all customers?

Comment: Same tables for all customers.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new table for each customer would be an absolute nightmare on several levels.  You would want to separate your data (in different tables) based-on category, but definitely not by customer.  So each customer would have an entry in the "Customer" table, and an entry in the "ShippingAddress" table, etc.  As long as you create your tables with appropriate indexes (and have adequate hardware) performance should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a database modeling design question not only specific for cloud application. Keeping common attributes in common tables always a best design approach for your application. The are many techquines to improve the performance for e.g indexing. In term of inactive customer tables you can design an archiving solution to reduce the size of the db.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this is for each customer you would like to have a Product and Invoice table for each customer ie ProductCustomer1, ProductCustomer2?  Is that correct?  I would view that as a nightmare to deal with unless you only had a few customers and didn’t care about making the database scalable.  Generally the best way would be to make the following tables each with their own primary key (customers, products, invoices, invoiceProducts).  The invoiceProducts table is because there is a many to many relationship between invoices and products that belong on an invoice.  You can then configure constraints in the foreign key for on delete operations. This will be the simplest to backup/restore (if need be).  Did I understand your question correctly?  If need be I can provide a database diagram if that would help.